# Preventing antialiasing from CALayer renderInContext

Tags: ios, calayer

I have a very simple `UIView` containing a few black and white `UIImageView`s.   If I take a screenshot via the physical buttons on the device, the resulting image looks exactly like what I see (as expected) - if I examine the image at the pixel level it is only black and white.

However, if I use the following snippet of code to perform the same action programmatically, the resulting image has what appears to be anti-aliasing applied - all the black pixels are surrounded by faint grey halos.   There is no grey in my original scene - it's pure black and white and the dimensions of the "screenshot" image is the same as the one I am generating programmatically, but I can not seem to figure out where the grey haloing is coming from.

```
UIView *printView = fullView;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(printView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[printView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I've tried adding the following before the call to `renderInContext` in an attempt to prevent the antialiasing, but it has no noticeable effect:

```
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, NO);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, NO);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);
```

Here is a sample of the two different outputs - the left side is what my code produces and the right side is a normal iOS screenshot:

[image]

Since I am trying to send the output of my `renderInContext` to a monochrome printer, having grey pixels causes some ugly artifacting due to the printer's dithering algorithm.

So, how can I get `renderInContext` to produce the same pixel-level output of my views as a real device screenshot - i.e. just black and white as is what is in my original scene?

Comment: Does the layer have a non-identity transform?  How are the layer's contents drawn?

Comment: The view layout is very simple - I have a UIView which contains another UIView, which in turn contains a UIImageView.  There are no transformations being applied.  The contents are drawn using all default iOS behavior for UIView's and UIImageView's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the problem was related to the resolution of the underlying `UIImage` being used by the `UIImageView`.  The `UIImage` was a `CGImage` created using a data provider.  The `CGImage` dimensions were specified in the same units as the parent `UIImageView` however I am using an iOS device with a retina display.

Because the `CGImage` dimensions were specified in non-retina size, `renderInContext` was upscaling the CGImage and apparently this upscaling behaves differently than what is done by the actual screen rendering. (For some reason the real screen rendering upscaled without adding any grey pixels.)

To fix this, I created my `CGImage` with double the dimension of the `UIImageView`, then my call to `renderInContext` produces a much better black and white image.  There are still a few grey pixels in some of the white area, but it is a vast improvement over the original problem.

I finally figured this out by changing the call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` to force it to do a scaling of 1.0 and noticed the `UIImageView` black pixel rendering had no grey halo anymore.  When I forced `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` to a scale factor of 2.0 (which is what it was defaulting to because of the retina display), then the grey haloing appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to set the

```
 printView.layer.magnificationFilter
```

and

```
 printView.layer.minificationFilter
```

to

```
 kCAFilterNearest
```

Are the images displayed in `UIImageView` instances? Is `printView` their superview?

Comment: I added the faulty screenshot image generated by my code compared to a true screenshot from my iOS device.  Yes, the images are shown in UIImageView instances.  Yes, printView is their superview.  The output generated by my code looks similar to what happens when a bitmap doesn't match the same dimensions as the containing UIImageView, but in this case, the size matches exactly.   The small blocks in my sample image are 8 pixels across as they are in both captured screenshots, but for some reason my code acts as if they fall on a 1/2 pixel boundary.

Comment: So I guess the `kCAFilterNearest`trick didn't work? What about setting this value for each of the image views' layers?

Comment: Yes, kCAFilterNearest didn't make any observable difference.  I'll try it for each image view's layer.     I'm beginning to suspect the problem might lie within the image library I am using - it is a QRCode encoder and the UIImage it produces is using a CGImage with a data provider. I had assumed it was producing a bitmap image that matched my requested dimensions, but given it is using a data provider, I think it is doing some additional rendering on the fly.

Comment: I noticed that if I set shouldRasterize to YES for the image view layer, then the same problem occurs with a real iOS screenshot, but then if I then use kCAFilterNearest for the mag/min filter for the same image view layer, the alignment on the screen is correct and the iOS screenshot is correct.  But, unfortunately this has no effect on my call to renderInContext and that image is still exhibiting the grey haloing.